# Can two strings arguments be passed to a python dict() built in function?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pexpect

I have a loop i would like to build a dictionary from.  The part of the code I'm having trouble with is that both the key and the value are strings.  I cannot convert the IP variable back string into a int nor is it a float.

Here is the method from my class I'm attempting to build the dictionary with.  There is a loop elsewhere walking the IP range I'm interested in feeding the method parameter 'ip'.

```
def dictbuild(self,ip):
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    s.force_password = True
    try:
        s.login(str(ip), 'root', 'password')
        s.sendline('hostname')   # run a command
        s.prompt()             # match the prompt
        out = s.before        # print everything before the prompt, this returns a byte object and could need decode(utf-8)
        out = out.decode('utf-8')
        out = out.split()
        out = out[1]
        print(type(out)) #These type function give us an easy output of data types in the traceback
        print(type(ip))

        ipdict = dict(out=ip) ###Getting stuck here on two string types.
        print(ipdict)
        s.logout()
    except (pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, pexpect.EOF) as e:
        pass
```

Instead of passing the string i want (it would actually be the hostname of the box) we get an output like this...

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
{'out': '10.20.234.3'}
```

The python documentation only gives examples of key as string and value as int.  Am i using this wrong?

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was the input of `self, ip` for the output given?

Comment: This is a method of a class, so self is the current instance of the object, ip is a string like this '10.20.234.3'.  The hostname would look something like this 'P-2301'.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict literal instead:

```
ipdict = { out: ip }
```

Calling `dict()` in that way is just passing named arguments; dict literals take expressions for keys and expressions for values.

Comment: The Traceback (using python3.3)...  File "ipchk_v2.py", line 53
    ipdict = dict{out:ip}
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @jonnymac: Compare the two lines. Yours should not have `dict{` in it.

Comment: You are correct, it really was a syntax error. Much better.